# Adding data to existing Excel worksheet in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm currently working on creating a minesweeper game in Visual Studio C#, and i would like to add a feature that can tell the player both their winrate and average time.

Is there a way for me to create an excel worksheet, and transfer data from my program to that worksheet?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=npoi)

It's easy to use

```
   IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        ISheet sheet1 = workbook.CreateSheet("References");

        int row = 0;

        IRow excelrow = sheet1.CreateRow(row);
        excelrow.CreateCell(3, CellType.Numeric).SetCellValue(dataList.Total_items);
```